# What do the ending sounds in Cantonese sentences mean or convey?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, cantonese

I think it's pretty well known that Cantonese has a lot of a's and la's attached to the end of sentences. However as a non-native, I have trouble understanding when these are used. For example, when using Pimsleur Cantonese, I've noticed yes/no questions usually have this structure:

你想唔想水啊？

For making suggestions, I've noticed its something like this:

咁，九點啦?

Sometimes I see something like this and I have no clue:

我唔鍾意太濃嘅茶 (the ge or ga sometimes at the end)

Is there a good guide out there for understanding these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question cannot be explained with a sample answer

In Cantonese, different final particles can express different emotions and different implications. Sometimes it just serves as an emphasis to the whole sentence

To learn them all, one must listen to and speak Cantonese daily for a long time

One simple example:

係(yes/correct)

係呀 - 呀 here usually implies agreement (supportive/ confirm)

係嘅 - 嘅 here usually implies agreement (with obedience)

係咩 - 咩 here marks it as a questioning form

係吔 - 吔 here implies challenge (yes, so?)

係囉噃 - 囉噃 here indicates requesting a promise

係啦 - 啦 here usually implies promising

Example:

A: "咁係囉噃?" = "then it is so, ok.?"

B: "係啦 ~~" = "yes ~~" (promising with a hint of annoyance)

Depending on the tone of the speech, final particles can express a wide range of emotions like annoyed, shock, realization, doubt

嘅 in 我唔鍾意太濃嘅茶 is not a final particle. It is the Cantonese version of the adjective marker 的

The second 嘅 in 我唔鍾意太濃嘅茶嘅 is a final particle, it is for emphasis

Comment: Thank you. I think either way that is a useful sample answer of what I'm needing.